# Firebase user sometimes nil, depending on used platform

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm building an iOS swift app using XCode and Firebase. This is my login state handler:

```
FIRAuth.auth()!.addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
        if user != nil{
            let fullName = user?.displayName
            print("logged in: " + fullName!)
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: self.loginToFeed, sender: nil)
        }
    }
```

This works on the iPhone 7+ emulator and sends me to my feed. However, now the problem: when I switch to a iPhone 5s phone or emulator (all on 10.2.0!), it does not work. The problem is that on the state change `auth.currentUser` and `user` are always nil. The Google signin pages shows up and lets me sign in. After the signin nothing happens, because those values are nil.

My controller is a `GIDSignInUIDelegate`, and I'm using `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()` to trigger the login.

I really don't understand what is happening as the code works on the iPhone 7+ emulator.